# Does Google Tag Manager dataLayer expose PII?

Tags: e-commerce, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

Using GTM for ecommerce tracking with the dataLayer option says that a transactionId is required to be passed. How is that information not personally identifying information? The transaction is made by a single user and can therefore be tracked back to that user in our system.

Is the rule about sending PII that it only matters if someone outside of my company can identify the user? It seems very unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a lawyer, but the [terms of service say](https://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html)

> You will not and will not assist or permit any third party to, pass
>   information to Google that Google could use or recognize as personally
>   identifiable information.

Google cannot identify a user from your transaction id, so (it would seemt that) this is in accordance with the TOS.

Your relevant legislation might see transaction ids as PII, and you would therefore not be permitted to store them, but that is outside the scope of general terms of service; you are yourself responsible for staying within applicable law.

Btw. this is not really about the dataLayer and Google Tag Manager, since GTM does not store the datalayer and the dataLayer itself is local to the visitors browser. This is a Google Analytics issue.

Comment: Thank you! This was my interpretation as well but I wanted to see if anyone else drew the same conclusion without being lead there. :)